# Eclipse is running the wrong class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a class, and wrote some code. When I try to run it, it runs the previous class that I was in. How do I make it run the class that I am in? When I try to run a different class than this one, it runs perfectly.

Comment: You have provided no information we can use to help.

Comment: Let's all fire up our psychic powers and figure this one out, ok?

Comment: Your run config is probably pointed at that class.  Eclipse is really good IDE, it's very high quality

Comment: Eclipse isnt running the class i am currently working on (when trying to compile it) instead another class i have

Comment: Any idea how to change my "run config"? and i aint claming that Eclipse has done anything wrong

Comment: Leave your configuration as is. Go to your project and right click. Then select Run/Debug Properties and associate the class you want to run for this project. Ideally every project should have one main method.

Comment: @CostisAivalis `main` methods are often used as ad-hoc sanity-checks instead of tests; they're noisy, but not really a major issue. An app's actual entry point will be decided in the manifest (or manually) anyway.

Comment: The basic trouble with your question is that you do not specify details, which makes it impossible to provide a precise answer to. Read a little other SO questions in order to get a better idea about how to ask.

Answer (score 59):

[image]

Your run configuration is wrong.

---

Under the `Run` menu there's a `Run Configurations` option. That defines the various run configs for your projects. You need to add a new one that runs whatever it is you're interested in.

Run configurations are also accessible by right-clicking in a Java source file, selecting `Run As...`, and `Run Configurations`.

Once you're in the run configuration dialog:

- edit the project if necessary (it won't be, using the right-click method)
- enter the class where the `main` method of interest resides
- give the configuration a reasonable name (optional, but handy)

Now you have a convenient way of selecting which `main` method you want to execute.

Comment: +1 : I need to save this pic for future ;)

Comment: Very nice, but how do i change the run config?

Comment: Couldnt find any way to fix it in there so i created a whole new project, no big harm done as you  see i am still in learning stage

Comment: @user1104692 Seems like a lot of extra work. I updated the answer again with some more specifics--all you need to do is enter the class name where the `main` method is.

Comment: hehehe hope baterry included ??? +1

Comment: to late now but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Abbac Wouldn't you rather learn to do it right?

Comment: sometimes I wish SO had an option "share on facebook" :)

Comment: make sure your code's main function has "static" keyword!