# Eclipse won't run desired program

Tags: java, eclipse

I open Eclipse, and then I open a class in a package. When I press Ctrl + F11, it runs some other program and not the program I have opened currently. And this happens with only those classes which I typed after updating Eclipse. All the classes before run perfectly fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse is running the wrong class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553175/eclipse-is-running-the-wrong-class)

Comment: Did you change the launch behavior of Eclipse?  Default is to launch the previously selected application.  Go to Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching.

Comment: Turns out I didn't write public Infront of static void main.. Feels like a noob right now